# NPAPI support for <video> tag

Tags: npapi

I know that I can use a NPAPI plugin with `<embed>` tag, but I was wondering is it possible to implement NPAPI plugin that will be called for `<video>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no automatic fallback from `<video>` to NPAPI plugins. If you wanted to use an NPAPI plugin to handle `<video>` you'd need to make an extension for each browser that would rewrite `<video>` tags on pages to be `<embed>`/`<object>` instead.

Comment: I suspected that it was impossible, but wanted to check. Thanks for your help.